# Restore Trash Script not working

Tags: scripting, mv, restore, trash

I made a script to send a file to a trash folder...

```
echo "Are you sure you want to move this file to the Recycle Bin?" "(Yes/No)"
read ans
case "$ans" in
Yes) echo "$(readlink -f "$1")" >> "$HOME/TrashLog" && mv "$1" "$HOME/my-documents/mydir01/Trash" ;;
No) echo "File was NOT deleted and remains. "
esac
```

This works.

The issue is, i am trying to create a script to "restore" the item in the trash back to where it came from.

here's what i have so far..

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$HOME/my-documents/mydir01/Trash" || exit 1
mv -i "$(grep "$1" "$HOME/TrashLog")"
```

(TrashLog - stores the filepath of the deleted file (so it can be restored later)
Trash - is the recycle bin directory I made)

Comment: @don_crissti so... the file path where the file is going to be returned is "TrashLog". ie, blah/blsf/hjhf.

So i would just type mv -i "$(grep "$1" "$HOME/TrashLog")" "$HOME/my-documents/"

That gives me an error along the lines of "cannot stat" or something?

Comment: Sorry, I meant you need to specify the source (i.e. ARGV1) not the destination, e.g. `mv -i "$1" "$(grep "$1" "$HOME/trashlog")"` as the missing argument makes `mv` interpret "$(grep "$1" "$HOME/TrashLog")" as the source and it complains about `missing destination file operand after`

Comment: @don_crissti
Ok... sorry if i seem confused, been a long 12 hours.
So I did this.. here is what i currently have. (Still getting a similiar error).

cd "$HOME/my-documents/mydir01/Trash" || exit 1
mv -i "$1" "$(grep "$1" "$HOME/TrashLog")"

Any thoughts as to what i'm supposed to be doing - i guess it's syntax or something.. honestly not too sure.

Comment: @don_crissti to run the script I would type..

restore <filename> in this case..

restore test.

Comment: @don_crissti
ok, so i load up console. I type:
restore test
The error i get is..
mv: cannot move 'test' to '/root/my-documents/mydir01/Trash/test\n/root/my-documents/mydir01/test': No such file or directory.

Comment: That's because you ran the first script twice and you got two matching entries in your TrashLog, hence `$(grep "$1" "$HOME/TrashLog")` expands to `/root/my-documents/mydir01/Trash/test\n/root/my-documents/mydir01/test` instead of `/root/my-documents/mydir01/Trash/test`. Delete all entries in your TrashLog and retry with only one file. It should work for that simple case. As soon as you delete more files, things get complicated... as `grep` might return multiple matches. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish but you gotta do some reading. And don't run stuff as root. Just DON'T.

Comment: Thankyou so very much for your patience. I can't believe how long i've sat here for someone to point out my issue easily. Again thankyou for your time, i've clearly still got a lot to learn :P - Thanks once again!